# Is there an R function that will allow me to create a dummy variable based on a date being within a range?

Tags: r, date

I have high frequency data in the following form, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' in Column A, there are no set intervals for this column. There is also another column of high frequency data in the same form, in Column B. Column B is in 5 minute intervals. I want to generate a dummy variable that equals 1 if the date in the Column A is equal to another cell in Column B, or alternatively it is between two of these timestamps.

For example, I have the timestamp 2018-01-01 09:12:00 in Column A, and in Column B I have the two timestamps 2018-01-01 09:10:00 followed by 2018-01-01 09:15:00. In this case, the dummy variable would equal 1 as the timestamp in column A falls between these two dates. The associated dummy variable would be in the same row as the first timestamp in Column B, 2018-01-01 09:10:00.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

data <- tibble(
  Col_A = structure(c(1514935860, 1514936280, 1514946120, 1515090600, 1515090600, 1515095040), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
  Col_B = structure(c(1517564040, 1517564340, 1517564640, 1517564940, 1517565240, 1517565540), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))  
)

data %>%
  mutate(a_in_b = Col_A  <= max(data$Col_B) & Col_A >= min(data$Col_B))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using this and while the code runs perfectly, I do not have two columns for the interval part of the dummy variable, only 1. Also, no dummy variable appears in my dataset, which I assume is due to the fact that my interval is different. I think if I could get the interval to be something like col_b, col_b +1 it may work, but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: To add to that, I have around 13000 observations in Column A and around 400,000 in Column B.

Comment: Please provide example data e.g. using `dput(head(df))`

Comment: Col_A = structure(c(1514935860, 
1514936280, 1514946120, 1515090600, 1515090600, 1515095040), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Col_B = structure(c(1517564040, 1517564340, 
1517564640, 1517564940, 1517565240, 1517565540), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")),

Comment: How do you want to define the interval of Col_B? Just set the new column to 1 if one element in a is within  `min(data$Col_B)` and  `max(data$Col_B)` ? Or are there many intervals?

Comment: What do you mean by many intervals? I think how you have described it fits it perfectly, if a timestamp in Col_A is between any timestamps in Col_B then the new column equals 1 at the timestamp of Col_A.

Comment: @RonanDunne I revised my answer

Comment: I tried running that code and I got the following error, error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "logical"

Comment: have you installed the tidyverse package?

Comment: Yes I have installed the tidyverse package

Comment: is your `data` object  NA?

Comment: There are some N/A data points in the data set due to other columns having more values than col_a and col_b. Would I be better off taking the two columns and putting them into their own object and then running the code?

Comment: Columns must be together in one data.frame Im asking because `dplyr::mutate(NA, x = 1)` results in the same error

Comment: My columns are together, but when I try use the code all of my values are NA, I used the exact code that you used and it worked for your 'data' object but when I try apply it to my dataset it doesn't work

Comment: Try to ensure that the columns are formatted as time points e.g. using `data$Col_A <- as.POSIXct(data$Col_A)` before `mutate`. This is required by functions `min` and `max`. You will get `NA` if they are formated as `character`

Comment: I tried to do that and I received the following code relating to Col_B;

Comment: Error in rep.default(t0, length) : invalid 'times' argument